# Why should functions always return the same type?

Tags: python, function, return-type

I read somewhere that functions should always return only one type
so the following code is considered as bad code:

```
def x(foo):
 if 'bar' in foo:
  return (foo, 'bar')
 return None
```

I guess the better solution would be

```
def x(foo):
 if 'bar' in foo:
  return (foo, 'bar')
 return ()
```

Wouldn't it be cheaper memory wise to return a None then to create a new empty tuple or is this time difference too small to notice even in larger projects?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Why should functions return values of a consistent type?  To meet the following two rules.

Rule 1 -- a function has a "type" -- inputs mapped to outputs.  It must return a consistent type of result, or it isn't a function.  It's a mess.

Mathematically, we say some function, F, is a mapping from domain, D, to range, R.  `F: D -> R`.  The domain and range form the "type" of the function.  The input types and the result type are as essential to the definition of the function as is the name or the body.

Rule 2 -- when you have a "problem" or can't return a proper result, raise an exception.

```
def x(foo):
    if 'bar' in foo:
        return (foo, 'bar')
     raise Exception( "oh, dear me." )
```

You *can* break the above rules, but the cost of long-term maintainability and comprehensibility is astronomical.

"Wouldn't it be cheaper memory wise to return a None?"  Wrong question.

The point is *not* to optimize memory at the cost of clear, readable, obvious code.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence.  Maintainability is the real cost that should be considered with 99% of code.

Comment: You haven't really given any reasons for this conclusion though. Your reasons why a function should return the same type include 1) "any function that does otherwise is a mess", and 2) "it must return the same type to fit the mathematical definition of a function." The first is pure rhetoric, and the second begs the question. It's not that I disagree. I readily defer to your python prowess. But could you give some practical reasons on why people should observe this practice? For example, breaking with this practice surely wouldn't <i>always</i> make code unreadable.

Comment: -1: When the word 'function' is used in the context of this question it is reasonable to assume it means a Python function, not a mathematical function. It's quite normal for Python functions to not always return the same type (e.g. `copy.copy()`). Your Rule 1 says that some Python functions aren't really functions, which is a semantic mess.

Comment: The `copy.copy()` is still a function.  The signature (domain and range) are fixed.  For a given domain value, the range is predictable.  Yes, there are a lot of combinations, but the combinations are trivially predictable.  It's a function with a simple, predictable signature in a mathematical sense.  It does not spontaneously return an unpredictable type.

Comment: @Scott Griffiths: the point is to *reduce* complexity, by reasoning about things we can know and understand.  By limiting ourselves to functions that mirror mathematical formalisms, we have a fighting chance of creating software that really works.  That's the "why".

Comment: There are also lots of examples in the standard library that either return one type or return `None`. They don't 'spontaneously return an unpredictable type' any more then the OP's function. For example `os.getenv', `re.search`, `sys.callstats`. Raising an exception instead is a fine thing to do, but it's a design choice, and returning `None` is often quite reasonable.

Comment: Interestingly, many of the counter examples -- functions that actually return an unpredictable type -- are inherited from OS library routines that are forced to cater to the C API, which lacks exceptions.  Making them bad examples of Pythonic things to do.  The only relevant example, so far, is `re.search` which spontaneously returns an expected value -- a object which is not of class `Match`.  And that's often frustrating because of all the extra if-statements required.

Comment: And what happens if i want to say `[x(foo) for foo in seq]`?

Comment: @David X:  The expression -- as a whole -- is ill-formed because one part is ill-formed.  That's the most logical because it's the most consistent and easiest to reason with. If you're talking about using the list comprehension as some kind of "filter", then you'd have to actually write the actual filtering expression.  Consistency is easier to work with and a list of mixed values and `None`s is potentially confusing.

Comment: The ever so loved math-reference when it comes to programming functions is something I find very flawed and inaccurate: 1)a function doesn't need to have input, 2)a function doesn't need to have output (as in return something) and 3)a function doesn't have to map the input to the output. Functional programming is something that comes as close to math functions as it gets (omho). But Python even though supporting lambda functions and all that is not a functional programming language. As for the multiple return types - you can always use an interface class of some sort.

Comment: And in what math course did you learn that the codomain of a function must be a programming language type?

Answer (score 28):

It's not so clear that a function must always return objects of a limited type, or that returning None is wrong. For instance, re.search can return a `_sre.SRE_Match` object or a `NoneType` object:

```
import re
match=re.search('a','a')

type(match)
# <type '_sre.SRE_Match'>

match=re.search('a','b')

type(match)
# <type 'NoneType'>
```

Designed this way, you can test for a match with the idiom

```
if match:
    # do xyz
```

If the developers had required re.search to return a `_sre.SRE_Match` object, then
the idiom would have to change to

```
if match.group(1) is None:
    # do xyz
```

There would not be any major gain by requiring re.search to always return a `_sre.SRE_Match` object.

So I think how you design the function must depend on the situation and in particular, how you plan to use the function.

Also note that both `_sre.SRE_Match` and `NoneType` are instances of object, so in a broad sense they are of the same type. So the rule that "functions should always return only one type" is rather meaningless.

Having said that, there is a beautiful simplicity to functions that return objects which all share the same properties. (Duck typing, not static typing, is the python way!)  It can allow you to chain together functions: foo(bar(baz))) and know with certainty the type of object you'll receive at the other end.

This can help you check the correctness of your code. By requiring that a function returns only objects of a certain limited type, there are fewer cases to check. "foo always returns an integer, so as long as an integer is expected everywhere I use foo, I'm golden..."

Comment: I think this is the best answer because it addresses the Python paradigm. Returning None is generally fine, no matter what else the function returns, as it is common practice to test a return value.
e.g.
x = foo()
if x:
   # do something

Anything other than 0, (), "", or None will equate to True.

Comment: even if `re.search` would always return a match object it could still be checked with `if match` -- if the `__nonzero__` function was implemented accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

Best practice in what a function should return varies greatly from language to language, and even between different Python projects.

For Python in general, I agree with the premise that returning None is bad if your function generally returns an iterable, because iterating without testing becomes impossible.  Just return an empty iterable in this case, it will still test False if you use Python's standard truth testing:

```
ret_val = x()
if ret_val:
     do_stuff(ret_val)
```

and still allow you to iterate over it without testing:

```
for child in x():
    do_other_stuff(child)
```

For functions that are likely to return a single value, I think returning None is perfectly acceptable, just document that this might happen in your docstring.

Comment: I really like the iterable vs. single value argument you made, but I think it needs to be tweaked just a bit -- what if the iterable is a tuple? A common python-ism for tuple-returning functions is, `a, b = x()`, which would raise a `TypeError` exception if None was returned. Also, strings are iterable _and_ a single value. Perhaps the argument should be a dynamic length iterable vs. a single value? Or, more generally perhaps, mutable vs. non-mutable?

Comment: If you're returning a fixed size tuple, then yes, I agree, returning None is a bad idea, but that's just a special case of "if callers would like to destructure your response without testing", which is already covered by "don't return None if it's iterable". Regarding strings, I think it's generally better to return empty string than None, but *very* occasionally empty string and None have different implications, in which case you should, again, document this.

Comment: `...'which is already covered by "don't return None if it's iterable".'` Oh, right. My mind must have skipped a beat. Well, I guess the string point still stands, thanks for covering that.

Answer (score 10):

Here are my thoughts on all that and I'll try to also explain why I think that the accepted answer is mostly incorrect.

First of all `programming functions != mathematical functions`. The closest you can get to mathematical functions is if you do functional programming but even then there are plenty of examples that say otherwise.

- Functions **do not** have to have input
- Functions **do not** have to have output
- Functions **do not** have to map input to output (because of the previous two bullet points)

A function in terms of programming is to be viewed simply as a block of memory with a start (the function's entry point), a body (empty or otherwise) and exit point (one or multiple depending on the implementation) all of which are there for the purpose of reusing code that you've written. Even if you don't see it a function always "returns" something. This something is actually the address of next statement right after the function call. This is something you will see in all of its glory if you do some really low-level programming with an Assembly language (I dare you to go the extra mile and do some machine code by hand like Linus Torvalds who ever so often mentions this during his seminars and interviews :D). In addition you can also take some input and also spit out some output. That is why

```
def foo():
  pass
```

is a perfectly correct piece of code.

So why would returning multiple types be bad? Well...It isn't at all unless you abuse it. This is of course a matter of poor programming skills and/or not knowing what the language you're using can do.

> > Wouldn't it be cheaper memory wise to return a None then to create a new empty tuple or is this time difference too small to notice even in larger projects?

As far as I know - yes, returning a `NoneType` object would be much cheaper memory-wise. Here is a small experiment (returned values are bytes):

```
>> sys.getsizeof(None)
16
>> sys.getsizeof(())
48
```

Based on the type of object you are using as your return value (numeric type, list, dictionary, tuple etc.) Python manages the memory in different ways including the initially reserved storage.

However you have to also consider the code that is around the function call and how it handles whatever your function returns. Do you check for `NoneType`? Or do you simply check if the returned tuple has length of 0? This propagation of the returned value and its type (`NoneType` vs. empty tuple in your case) might actually be more tedious to handle and blow up in your face. Don't forget - the code itself is loaded into memory so if handling the `NoneType` requires too much code (even small pieces of code but in a large quantity) better leave the empty tuple, which will also avoid confusion in the minds of people using your function and forgetting that it actually returns 2 types of values.

Speaking of returning multiple types of value this is the part where I agree with the accepted answer (but only partially) - returning a single type makes the code more maintainable without a doubt. It's much easier to check only for type A then A, B, C, ... etc.

However Python is an object-oriented language and as such inheritance, abstract classes etc. and all that is part of the whole OOP shenanigans comes into play. It can go as far as even generating classes on-the-fly, which I have discovered a few months ago and was stunned (never seen that stuff in C/C++).

*Side note:* You can read a little bit about metaclasses and dynamic classes in [this nice overview article](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/28/improve-your-python-metaclasses-and-dynamic-classes-with-type/) with plenty of examples.

There are in fact multiple design patterns and techniques that wouldn't even exists without the so called polymorphic functions. Below I give you two very popular topics (can't find a better way to summarize both in a single term):

- [Duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) - often part of the dynamic typing languages which Python is a representative of
- [Factory](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Factory.html) method design pattern - basically it's a function that returns various objects based on the input it receives.

Finally whether your function returns one or multiple types is totally based on the problem you have to solve. Can this polymorphic behaviour be abused? Sure, like everything else.

Comment: _"returning a NoneType object would be much cheaper memory-wise."_ - not true, both cost 8 bytes (the `PyObject *` pointer), and both `()` and `None` are global constants allocated at startup.

Answer (score 7):

I personally think it is perfectly fine for a function to return a tuple or None. However, a function should return at most 2 different types and the second one should be a None. A function should never return a string and list for example.

Comment: Also, a function that returns either a 3-uple or a 0-uple as in the example, looks bad taste to me. "return None" is also my preferred choice in this example case.

Answer (score 4):

If `x` is called like this

```
foo, bar = x(foo)
```

returning `None` would result in a

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

if `'bar'` is not in `foo`.

**Example**

```
def x(foo):
    if 'bar' in foo:
        return (foo, 'bar')
    return None

foo, bar = x(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
print foo, bar

foo, bar = x(["foo", "NOT THERE", "baz"])
print foo, bar
```

This results in:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f.py", line 9, in <module>
    foo, bar = x(["foo", "NOT THERE", "baz"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil. The minuscule efficiency gains might be important, but not until you've proven that you need them.

Whatever your language: a function is defined once, but tends to be used at any number of places. Having a consistent return type (not to mention documented pre- and postconditions) means you have to spend more effort **defining** the function, but you simplify the **usage** of the function enormously. Guess whether the one-time costs tend to outweigh the repeated savings...?