# a function returns a certain (object or value) based on a rule

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, python-3.x, uml

Lets suppose i have this function in python:

```
def get_thing(rule):
    if rule == 0:
        return 5         #<<<< int
    elif rule == 1:
        return 'Hello'   #<<<<< string
    else:
        return Student() #<<<<< Object
```

The above function returns a different values(int or string or object) based on a rule.

Should i use the above function or use this functions:

```
def get_int()
    return 5

def get_string()
    return 'Hello'

def get_student()
    return Student()
```

I mean is it pythonic to a function to return different datatypes or values?

In java you can return only one type Ex: String only.

I hope you understand my question :)

Thanks.

EDIT:
Other example

```
def get_person(id):
    if #id is belongs to student:
        return Student()
    elif #id belongs to teacher
        return Teacher()
```

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I think you're going to have to give more context for this question. That being said, the first snippet doesn't look like a good solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1839350/834998

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to return values of different types from a function in Python. As far as the implementation is concerned, consider using dictionaries instead of nested ifs, e.g.:

```
def get_thing(rule):
    return { 0 : 5, 1 : 'Hello'}.get(rule, Student())
```

Comment: It's OK in the sense that Python will allow it, but it's not a good practice for maintenance. See PartiallyFinite's link in the comment above.

Comment: It depends on the situation. There are many situations it is absolutely fine. Python's got the duck typing for a reason.

Comment: The last example you gave is a good example. A Student and Teacher can be returned from a function even in a statically typed language like C++ or Java if they both have a common base class (Person), and this is really a fine OO design.

Comment: What about if they are not inherited from class Person?

Comment: Then it's OK if they share a common behaviour (have the same looking methods or attributes), that's what we call duck typing. Even if it's only ability to be printed/converted to string, whatever is expected from the thing you return from that function.

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question :), i will search more about duck typing.