# Can print function catch None return value and not print it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, types

I am new and learning Python. What is the best way to avoid printing None in the code below? I commented out raising an error.

I know why None is being printed. I would have liked to have 2 return types for the function but apparently that is bad practice for maintainability of the code according to S.Lott's response on [Why should functions always return the same type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839289/why-should-functions-always-return-the-same-type). Moreover, unutbu's answer on the same post where errors will pop up when you call the function within a function expecting a certain type - fun1(fun2(arg)). I don't want to raise a runtime error as S.Lott suggested. Is there a way of print catching the None value and not printing it?

```
def smaller_root(a,b,c):
    """
    akes an input the numbers a,b and c returns the smaller solution to this 
    equation if one exists. If the equation has no real solution, print 
    the message, "Error: No Real Solution " and simply return.
    """
    discriminant = b**2-4*a*c

    if discriminant == 0:
        return  -b/(2*a)
    elif discriminant > 0:
        return (-b-discriminant**0.5)/(2*a) #just need smaller solution
    else:
        print("Error: No Real Solution")
        #raise Exception("Error: No Real Solution")
        #no return statement as there is no use for it. 
        #Python will implicitly return None
```

Comment: Return `None` and avoid printing it when you call the function. If you raise an exception `None` won't be returned, but I don't think exception is good as an indication that no solution was found.

Comment: @MarounMaroun On the contrary, this is a good case for exceptions. Most importantly: "Errors should never pass silently."

Comment: @Rhymoid It's not an error; it's just that there's no solution.

Comment: @MarounMaroun If it's a situation that (the rest of) the program can't deal with, it should be modeled as an error.

Comment: @Rhymoid I think it's a matter of design, as long as you're consistent you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your function do *one*, and only *one*, thing. So, in your case, it should find the `smaller_root` according to some variables.

The return value of your function should be the root. In your case, it is possible that it returns `None`, which would indicate that there is no root for the solution.

However, you are trying to make the function do **more than one** thing, that is, you are trying to make the function return a value (the root) AND print out a message if no root is found.

You should choose one functionality only for you function: It will *EITHER* print out the result (that is, print a root or a message) *OR* return the result.

Every other logic beyond that of the functionality would be out of the function's scope, e.g.:

```
def smaller_root(a,b,c):
    """
    akes an input the numbers a,b and c returns the smaller solution to this 
    equation if one exists. If the equation has no real solution, print 
    the message, "Error: No Real Solution " and simply return.
    """
    discriminant = b**2-4*a*c

    if discriminant == 0:
        return  -b/(2*a)
    elif discriminant > 0:
        return (-b-discriminant**0.5)/(2*a) #just need smaller solution
    else:
        return None

result = smaller_root(some_a, some_b, some_c)
if (result is None):
    print("Error: No Real Solution")
```