# Changing number of returned values depending on number of passed arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Is there a short way for performing operations on tuple of arguments `*args` that returns single argument if single argument was passed into a function and tuple of arguments otherwise?** Like in the following example.

```
def transform(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0] + 1
    else:
        return tuple(arg + 1 for arg in args)
```

Such that for single argument you can simply invoke transform without additional unpacking:

```
x = transform(3)
```

As well as for multiple arguments:

```
a, b, c = transform(1, 2, 3)
```

Other option would be to say always take in Sized and return Sized,

```
def transform_2(args):
    return tuple(arg + 1 for arg in args)
```

But it seems to make user code less intuitive:

```
x, = transform_2((3,))
a, b, c = transform_2((1, 2, 3))
```

**Or is this solution better?**

Comment: You shouldn't do this. It breaks the single return type rule. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839289/why-should-functions-always-return-the-same-type

Comment: @FHTMitchell I don't think it breaks that rule, input type for `transform(3)` is single integer, input type for `transform(1, 2, 3)` is tuple of three integers and I'm returning object of the same type.

Comment: @DikobrAz Your function doesn't have a single return type. It returns values of different types *depending on the type of the argument*.

Comment: Well, not exactly. If you're input was a tuple then it'd be written as `transform((1, 2, 3))`. In a formal type system `(Int) -> T1` is a supertype of `(Int, Int?, Int?) -> T2` and so `T2` must be a subtype of `T1` (here I use `?` to mean optional, not nullable as in Kotlin). I agree, a function that looks like `(T) -> T` is acceptable.

Comment: Even a function with type `(T) -> T` isn't really a single function; it's a *schema* for a whole class of functions like `(Int) -> Int`, `(Char) -> Char`, etc.

Comment: @chepner Yes, but the point is that it doesn't break a type system. C# is perfectly happy with `static T Method<T>(T arg)` (I think).

Comment: @jpp can you please reopen the question - I've changed it to follow the discussion and I can answer it properly now.

Answer (score 2):

An API that *always* takes an iterable is easier to understand and doesn't put *that* great a burden on the user.

```
def transform(args):
    return tuple(arg + 1 for arg in args)

x = transform((3,))  # or transform([3])
a, b, c = transform([1,2,3])
```

Any attempt to do what you are trying to do breaks down if you try to pass a string, since you *probably* intend `foo("123")` to return a single value, not the result of `foo("1")`, `foo("2")`, and `foo("3")`, but short of explicitly testing for `str`, you aren't going to be able to distinguish between a string argument and another iterable.

Comment: Can you please clarify? It's not obvious why is it more user friendly.

Comment: @asynts The question starts from a faulty premise.

Comment: @chepner in the example that I've given `transform("123")` is actually doing what expected - transforming "123" and not transforming "1" and "2" and "3".

Comment: @DikobrAz Yes, and your function is far more complicated and difficult to test and maintain than one that simply does one thing (modify each element of an iterable) and leaves it to the caller to provide an iterable.

Comment: @chepner I agree that it is more difficult to maintain, that is why I'm asking this question to see if there is nicer solution. But the user needs to write less code and it looks very intuitive. Also it seems less error prone, in your example if user accidentally calls `transform("123")` instead of `transform(("123",))` then he will get `transform("1"), transform("2"), transform("3")` which is undesired and I won't be able to check this situation and raise an error.

Comment: Problem: user doesn't know that strings are iterable. Solution: user learns that strings are iterable. Problem solved. If you want, you can provide two separate functions, `transform` and `transform_all`. But don't try to make a single function that tries to be everything to everyone.