# Is it good code style if a Python function returns different types depending on the arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Is it good code style if a Python function returns different types depending on the arguments provided?**

```
def foo(bar):
  if bar is None:
    return None
  elif bar == 1:
    return 1*1
  else:
    return [b*b for b in bar]
```

`foo` returns `None` if bar is None

`foo` return `1` if `bar == 1`

`foo` returns a List of `int` if bar is a Tuple / List of integers

Examples:

```
>> foo(None)
None
>> foo(1)
1
>> foo(1, 2, 3, 4)
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Returning `None` or an `int` should be OK, but is it OK to return an `int` or a list of `int`s depending on the function arguments? You could argue that it would be OK because the user knows which return types to expect and doesn't need type checking (in which case I would say it's not OK), but one could argue that it would be better to split the function into two functions, one expecting a `int` and return an `int` and one expecting a list of `int` and returning a list of `int`s.

Comment: And what about `foo(2)` or `foo('asd')`? you need to handle more cases, if it's good practice or not is up to you.

Comment: It depends entirely on the use case - for instance, `json.loads(x)` returns different types depending on the value of `x`.

Comment: in my opinion it's ok if you document it

Comment: @Guy: I'm aware that the example is not complete and would need more checks to handle different input. I wanted to keep the example short.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: nooooooo. Return the most restricted type possible. Think abut it this way: how would you type this function using the typing module? The type would either be `Any` or a `Union`. That’s usually a sign of trouble. There are exceptions, but they’re quite specific.

Comment: In Haskell you have sumtypes which is very similar to what you describe. So I say yes it is ok as long as you document it.

Comment: it depends, it happens in the standard library, e.g. `type(round(1.0, 1))` vs. `type(round(1, 1))`  via delegation to `float.__round__` and `int.__round__`. This happens with other attributes too, like `format()` (str or bytes)

Comment: @Elmex80s Sum types are *similar* but by offer several important guarantees that this function’s return type doesn’t offer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes true. Therefore you need to document it very well. I shouldn't have used the word "exactly". Thanks.

Comment: maybe duplicate with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839289/why-should-functions-always-return-the-same-type

Comment: Unless the use case is very very specific I would say no. Personally I prefer not to for readability purposes and to more fluently use the function in a more complex program. Functions are reusabble at their core and thus splitting them and using them according to what the input/output is would be more fitting to me.

Answer (score 5):

It depends entirely on your use case. Here's an example in the standard library where the type of the result depends on the *type* of the input:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.add(1, 2)
3
>>> operator.add(1.0, 2.0)
3.0
```

This type of behavior is usually ok, and can be documented with `@typing.overload`.

---

Here's an example where the type of the result depends on the *value* of the input:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('1')
1
>>> json.loads('[1]')
[1]
```

This type of behavior is usually reserved for serialization and deserialization, or APIs which blur the type / value boundary such as `astype` in  `np.int_(3).astype(bool)`.

---

On the other hand, here's an example of a function which is obviously poorly designed:

```
from typing import Union  # make sure to document the mixed return type

def is_even(x: int) -> Union[bool, str]:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return "no"
```

Without knowing your specific use case, it's hard to give advice here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definite answer for this question and so formulating a clear comprehensive answer will be difficult, as can be seen in [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225682/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-return-different-data-types-from-a-single-function-in-a-dyna) very similar question.

In general, you should avoid returning different types from a function. As an example, I've once worked on a project where one function looked something like this:

```
def get_df(url):
    data = get_data(url)
    df = reformat_data(data)

    if df_is_empty(df):
        return 'Empty dataframe'

    df_interp = interpolate_df(df)
    return df_interp
```

You may imagine that when I got the error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

this was very confusing for me and it took about half a day to figure out where this error came from. A much better solution would have been to raise an `ValueError`.

Now, there always will be weird situations where this rule of thumb may be incorrect. For instance, when scraping websites, sometimes being able to retrieve images as well might be useful. In this case I'd include a flag in your function:

```
def scrape_website(url, get_images=False):
    data = do_stuff(url)
    ordered_data = order_data(data, get_images)
    return ordered_data
```

However I would rather split this up into two functions, one which returns the non-image data and one which returns only image data.