# How to type hint a function's optional return parameter?

Tags: python, type-hinting

How do I type hint an optional output parameter:

```
def myfunc(
        x: float, 
        return_y: bool = False
        ) -> float, Optional[float] : # !!! WRONG !!!

    # ... code here
    #
    # y and z are floats

    if return_y:
        return z, y

    return z
```

--- edit

This seem to work:

```
-> Tuple[float, Union[None, float]] :
```

but that is so ugly and seems to overwhelm the fact that typically it will only return a simple float.
Is that the correct way to do this?

See answer below for correct way.

--- edit 2

This question was flagged as duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints). However, *that* question is about `Union` return type, while *this* question is about `Optional` return type.

---

Note: this design is not a good practice and should be avoided in favour of a consistent return type. Still, in case it has to be done, by *optional output parameter* it is meant a parameter that may not be returned depending on an input argument's flag.

Comment: Your function either returns one float, or a tuple of two floats. So: `-> Union[float, Tuple[float, float]]`. The suggestion you give is wrong because in the single argument case, you don't return a `Tuple` at all.

Comment: Don't make the return type of your function depend on a runtime parameter. Either always return a tuple and let the user decide if they want to ignore the second element, or define two functions.

Comment: @chepner any specific reason why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since **Python 3.10** and [PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/) you now can use `|` instead of `Union`.

The return type would be `float | Tuple[float, float]`

---

The right type hint would be:

```py
from typing import Tuple, Union


def myfunc(x: float, return_y: bool = False) -> Union[float, Tuple[float, float]]:
    z = 1.5

    if return_y:
        y = 2.0
        return z, y

    return z
```

However, it is usually not a good practice to have these kinds of return. Either return something like `Tuple[float, Optional[float]]` or write multiple functions, it will be much easier to handle later on.

More about return statement consistency:

- [PEP8 - Programming Recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51)

> Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as return None, and an explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable).

- [Why should functions return values of a consistent type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1839350/5692012)

Comment: Thanks. My real case is a more complex  function root finding algorithm. The returned value is the root. Upon request, it can return convergence statistics and parameters for all interactions.  I may look into always retuning a tuple. But I'm hesitant in having to handle the additional returned argument in 99% of the cases. Any concrete arguments why the current design is a bad practice?

Comment: I've edited the answer with PEP8/SO references

Comment: `mypy` can't assume a particular value for `return_y`, and would flag something like `a, b = myfunc(3.14, x)` as an error, whether `x` was `True` or `False`.

Comment: @RobinFrcd thanks for adding references. Although I couldn't find them now, I remember some functions in SciPy or NumPy optionally changing what they return depending on user's flags. Anyway, convinced now, I decided to always return the tuple, and write a wrapper function to get only the root.