# Short circuit list of functions python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class with some method like this

```
class Validator:
    def _is_valid_code(self):
        return bool(#some logic here)

    def _is_valid_role(self):
        return bool(#some logic here)

    def _is_valid_age(self):
        return bool(#some logic here)
    .
    .
    .
```

if all of them are True I want to continue, else return a string

```
if not _is_valid_code():
    #short circuit and return a string
    return "not valid code"
if not _is_valid_role():
    #short circuit and return a string
    return "not valid role"
if not _is_valid_age():
    #short circuit and return a string with description
    return "not valid age"
#if we got here the request is valid so return a valid response
return valid_scenario
```

Now I do not have any problem with this because there are just three conditions, but for example, if I have more, let say like 10 conditions, I would end up with a lot of if scenarios, so I was thinking if something like this is possible, where I just add the condition logic and the condition to the list and that's it, the problem is to get the string value if the condition is false

```
conditions = [_is_valid_code(), _is_valid_role(), _is_valid_age()]
if all_conditions_true(conditions):
    return valid_scenario
else:
    return last_message_before_shortcut
```

Also want to know if this is valid and if this could be considered pythonic and recommended

Comment: Create list of pairs of methods/error strings. Then iterate over that list, calling the method and if it fails, return the string. Make this a class variable, so it actually saves you a good amount of time

Comment: I would not return a string in the event of an error. Have each function either return a valid scenario, or raise an exception. That way, if you return at all, you know you have the valid scenario.

Comment: I forgot mention that the return type is a json in all scenarios, actually I am returning a http code and a description when applies, the valid scenario differs from invalid because is a 204 without a message, the string was Just to ilustrate what I would like to do, but I have a several 403's where only the message is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
def one():
    """string from one"""
    return False 

def two():
    """string from two"""
    return False 

def three():
    """string from three"""
    return True

def four():
    """string from four"""
    return False

conditions=[one, two, three, four]
```

Then use `next` to find the first `True` or `False` as appropriate to read the associated doc string from the function:

```
>>> print( next(f.__doc__ for f in conditions if f()) )  
string from three
```

You can use a default with `next` to indicate all are the same (True or False as the case may be):

```
next((f.__doc__ for f in conditions if f()), "All False")
```

Or, as you stated the desire:

```
def validator(conditions):
    return next((f.__doc__ for f in conditions if f()), None)
```

Advantages:

1. If you use this approach in a class, the strings are automatically class in scope (not recreated each time);
2. Easier to edit (for me) than `[(one,"string from one"),(two,"string from two"),...]`;
3. String and associated test code are right there together in the function;
4. `next` with a conditional provides a short-circuit and stops at the first targeted boolean;
5. The list of conditions `[one,two,three,...]` is easier for ME to see and understand vs `[(one,"string from one"),(two,"string from two"),...]`
6. And one more thing! You can skip the `__doc__` string entirely and just use descriptive function names with:

   `next((f.__name__ for f in conditions if f()), default)`
7. If you want to do it *old school* you can use `next` with a dict of `func_name:"associated string"` as well.

Comment: This is way to clever by a half. Just use a list of tuples of method, msg

Comment: Personally I find this easier to maintain a function with an `__doc__` string vs list of tuples since each test result and code to test are in the same place. Works for me!

Comment: I use `__doc__` for these things, too. I wrote my answer to be most similar to what OP was used to (that is, to not change _too_ much at once). In my own projects, I'd absolutely have `if not function(): return function.__doc__`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict to store the functions mapped to their respective strings.

```
checks = {
    _is_valid_code: "not valid code",
    _is_valid_role: "not valid role",
    _is_valid_age: "not valid age",
    }

for f in checks:
    if not f():
        return checks[f]
return valid_scenario
```

Note that dicts preserve insertion order in Python 3.7+. If you're using an older version or want to be stricter about the ordering, use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) or list of tuples containing functions and strings.

---

This by itself is perfectly Pythonic, but I don't know the context so I can't say for sure in your case. For example, if `valid_scenario` isn't a string, I'd strongly recommend using exceptions instead of having a mixed return type. This question covers that: [Why should functions always return the same type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1839289/4518341) And I'd recommend the same if the functions are checking for **error** conditions.

Comment: This is fine, but I'd make that a list of tuples instead of a dictionary. You're not using any dict-specific behavior here.

Comment: @Kirk I'm using lookup in `checks[f]`. But yeah it doesn't need to be like that, it's just my way of thinking about it: if the function fails, only then do you need to get the associated string. You could just as well do `for f, s in checks.items()` or the equivalent on a list of tuples.

Comment: This should just be a list of pairs, but right general approach

Answer (score 2):

I've written these things like:

```
for condition_is_ok, error_msg in [
    (_is_valid_code, "not valid code"),
    (_is_valid_role, "not valid role"),
    (_is_valid_age, "not valid age"),
]:
    if not condition_is_ok():
        return error_msg
```

Alternatively, change the way your validators work:

- If they fail, return a string explaining why.
- If they pass, return None.

```
class Validator:
    def _code_error(self):
        if ...:
            return "not valid code"
        return None

for checker in [_code_error, ...]:
    result = checker
    if result is not None:
        return result
```

Comment: This is the correct approach *but don't recreate the list each time*. It should be a class variable

Comment: Definitely! Or if you can establish a naming pattern, you could use something like `for function in dir(cls): if function.startswith('_validate_'): ...` to inspect the class at runtime to collect all the defined validation functions. Why repeat yourself? Let Python help you be lazy.